# Get $data.length in variable in cshtml

Tags: knockout.js

I have to get the arraylist length in a variable in cshtml.

```html
<!-- ko foreach: Sales()-->
    <div data-bind="$data.length">
<!-- /ko -->
```

I need that `$data.length` to be saved in a variable like this:

```
@{int xyz = $data.length}
```

However, this is not working. I need it so that `xyz` can use be use in my Razor view.

Comment: $data.length is a knockout thing.  Where as @{} is a Razor thing.  That's why it isn't working.  Not sure of a solution for you though.

Comment: From what I've googled Razor is a viewEngine for ASP.NET, which means server-side. And your Knockout data lives client-side. So your options are: save it on submit of a `form` to an ASP.NET page, or use a JS ajax `POST` call to save it without redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this, not the way you seem to think this can be done. As per the comments, you should realize that there are two seperate things:

1. First, your *server* will execute your Razor view and create an html page with possibly some intermingled JavaScript. This is sent to the browser.
2. Second, the client's browser will execute the JavaScript.

So, you can't utilize `$data.length`'s value in your Razor view, because stage 1 is already done by the time the JavaScript's executed. Your options basically are:

1. Program whatever you want to do with `$data.length` in JavaScript;
2. Have your JavaScript code send `$data.length` to a controller action that renders a partial view (that Razor view will then have the value at its disposal for rendering).

Check out [Programmers.SE's explanation of the difference between Client and Server side code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/40625).